# Areospike handle high volume of requests to same index

Tags: database, autoscaling, aerospike

We have a use case where there may be a high volume of requests for the same key.  Aerospike routes requests to partitions based on a hash of the primary key.  Additional partitions and rebalancing can be happen to support higher traffic.  However, how can Aerospike handle the case where the hot spotting is caused by a single key?

Is there a better database solution for this case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This article has some input: https://discuss.aerospike.com/t/hot-key-error-code-14/986.

The first thing is to turn on the `[read-page-cache][1]`, and then spreading between different replicas... or, depending on the use, have multiple copies and reconcile on reads across them (depending if it is a write hotkey or a read one).

Comment: Thank you for the link and useful information.
The link says "There is no direct solution if a server is expected to handle hot-keys" and that it is important to filter out hotkeys on the client side or revisit the design.

Is it fair to say that using the read-page-cache solution shouldn't be used in all situations and if we're seeing hotkeys, then maybe something in the design should change?

Comment: I think that it depends. If the system can handle it, it can be just fine (the read-page-cache certainly alleviates the pressure to the disk if reading from a device but the network can then be a bottleneck). Spreading reads across replicas can also be good enough, or, finally, spreading over multiple keys (changing the data model).